# Java - Store string paths in table with JFileChooser, get set methods?

Tags: java, void, jfilechooser

I am designing an interface in which the user can select a file from with `JFileChooser` (initiated via `JButton`) and store its string path in a table, for later use. My code for selecting a file is contained within class `TheHandler`, and my table is within the class `FilePanel`.  I have the value of `filePath` directed to `tablePath` of class `FilePanel`, so that I can store the strings in the table.

However my issue is that `tablePath` returns `null`, which I think is either because:

1) `filePath` is contained within a `void` method

2) a value is given to `tablePath` before the user selects a file

or a combination of 1) and 2).  So my question is how I can extract the value of `filePath`, so that it can be taken by `tablePath` after the user selects a file?

I'm thinking get and set methods, but I just started learning about those, and from examples I've encountered, I would think I would need to utilize them within the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)` constructor, but if that's the case, I am completely thrown off on how to do that.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

`TheHandler` class:

```
public static class TheHandler implements ActionListener {
    String filePath;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Component parent = null;
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("TIFF Images", "tif", "tiff");
        chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);

        filePath = chooser.getSelectedFile().toString();
        //System.out.println(filePath);

        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            ImagePlus picture = IJ.openImage(filePath);
            picture.show();
        }
    }
}
```

`FilePanel` class:

```
public class FilePanel extends JPanel {
    public FilePanel() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        TheHandler thePath = new TheHandler();
        String tablePath = thePath.filePath;

        System.out.println(filePaths);    // outputs null, this line runs before file is chosen?

        String col[] = {"Loaded TIFF Files"};
        String[] tiffFiles = {filePaths, filePaths};   // Vector or list may be more useful?
        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(col, 0);
        tableModel.addRow(tiffFiles);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TheHandler is an ActionListener class pure and simple, and its main method, the overridden actionPerformed method, is only called if the component that The Handler is added to, be it a JButton, JMenuItem, or whatever, triggers its being called. You appear to be creating an instance of this class, but I don't see you adding it to any component that takes ActionListeners, so it should be no surprise that its one field, filePath, will remain null.

If you want to use this in a better way, then use it as an ActionListener is supposed to be used. Add it to a JButton or JMenuItem, and have it perform its action when an event dictates that the action should be performed. If you want to be notified that the filePath field is no longer null, you could make it a "bound property" by using SwingPropertyChangeSupport.

Option two is to create a method that performs the "meat" of the code in TheHandler's actionPerformed, and just call that outright when needed. You can even have TheHandler call this as well so it can serve a dual purpose.

e.g.,

```
public static class TheHandler implements ActionListener{
    String filePath;        

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){              
        String innerPath = null;
        innerPath = getFilePath();
        if (innerPath != null) {
            filePath = innerPath;
            ImagePlus picture = IJ.openImage(filePath); 
            picture.show();                                                                             
        }               
    }

    public String getFilePath() {
        String innerFilePath = null;
        Component parent = null; // better to avoid this
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("TIFF Images", "tif","tiff");
        chooser.setFileFilter(filter);      
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);   
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            innerFilePath = chooser.getSelectedFile().toString();                                               
        }  
        return innerFilePath;
    }
}
```

Then your other class could call TheHandler's `getFilePath()` method directly.

Comment: Oh I apologize, it was left out of my post, but I have the ActionListener coupled with a JButton to initiate the process:   addBtn.addActionListener(new TheHandler());   This makes sense though, let me see if I can get this working real quick

Comment: Aha, so correct me if I am wrong, but innerPath itself cannot be called, but by creating the getFilePath() method, innerPath take the value of innerFilePath when the conditions are satisfied, and since getFilePath() is a public method that returns innerFilePath, that method can be called in other classes.

Comment: Actually I have another question if you don't mind.  The method you created took out the filechooser (which will give me the desired string path) out of the void method, but invoking that method in another class will open a second filechooser (first one being when the load button is pressed).  Is there a way I can obtain just the return value of getFilePath() method, so that I can use that resulting string value in another class?